# Image.asset in a Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to insert an image into my widget but always get an error in the console and I don't know what to do about it.

```
class Menue extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 100),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset("Q-Extreme Menue.png"),
                  new IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: new Icon(null),),

                ],
                ),
                ....
```

I/flutter ( 8295): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 8295): Unable to load asset: Q-Extreme Menue.png
I/flutter ( 8295): 
I/flutter ( 8295): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8295): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter ( 8295): 
I/flutter ( 8295): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:44)
I/flutter ( 8295): 
I/flutter ( 8295): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:449:14)
I/flutter ( 8295): #3      ImageProvider.resolve... (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:316:48)
I/flutter ( 8295): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
I/flutter ( 8295): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:316:25)
I/flutter ( 8295): (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 8295): 
I/flutter ( 8295): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "Q-Extreme Menue.png")
I/flutter ( 8295): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#88838(), name: "Q-Extreme Menue.png",
I/flutter ( 8295):   scale: 1.0)

```
flutter:



  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
assets:
  - assets/images/Q-Extreme Menue.png
  - Q-Extreme Menue.png
```

Comment: Can you show your `pubspec.yaml` file, how you added the strings?

Comment: sure i post it under this post

Comment: Please add this to your question, it is difficult to understand in comment.

Comment: Okay I post as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image in a folder (`assets/images`) like as shown in the picture:

[image: image folder]

Then you can reference the asset in your pubspec.yaml (Be sure to remove the white spaces in the file name; you can call it `Q_Extreme_Menue.png`)

```
flutter:



  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets/images/Q_Extreme_Menue.png
```

Now when using the asset, you provide the full path:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/Q_Extreme_Menue.png'),
```

Comment: Now it says this. "/Users/myname/Desktop/BlackStories/black_stories/assets/images/Q-ExtremeMenue.png": file not found."

Comment: Make sure the file is the same as that specified in the pubspec file. And also ensure the file is in the right folder (asset (in the project root) -> images)

Comment: In which folder is your image located?

Comment: assets-->images-->Q_Extreme_Menue.png

Comment: Now it works but is there a possible solution to make the image smaller because I get this "A RenderFlex overflowed by 1333 pixels on the bottom."

Comment: Yes. Image.asset has height and width properties. `Image.asset('img.png'  height: 300, width: 400)`

Comment: And is it possible to move the image a bit to the left?

Answer (score 0):

I think you made mistake in indent spaces.

```
flutter:



  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets/images/Q-Extreme Menue.png
```

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get`?